# Is there a better way to join query in laravel eloquent.?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables and both have separate models from them. first table is users and other table is users_details table I am writing an eloquent query to join the result but I am getting following error

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'gender' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users_details` right join `users` on `users_details`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `gender` LIKE female and `matrimonial` LIKE 1)
```

my code for the query is following.

```
 public function bride(){

    $query = app(UserDetail::class)->newQuery(); 
    $query= $query->where('gender','LIKE','female');
    $query= $query->where('matrimonial','LIKE','1');
    $query = $query->rightJoin('users','users_details.user_id','=','users.id');
    $request = request();
      if(request()->exists('sort')){
        $sorts = explode(',',request()->sort);
        foreach ($sorts as $sort){
            list($sortCol, $sortDir) = explode('|',$sort);
            $query = $query->orderBy($sortCol,$sortDir);
         } 
    } 
     else { 
            $query = $query->orderBy('id','asc');
        }
  if($request->exists('filter')) {
      $query->where(function($q) use($request){
        $value = "%{$request->filter}%";
        $q->where('name','like',$value)
              ->orWhere('father_name','like',$value)
              ->orWhere('city','like',$value)
              ->orWhere('mother_name','like',$value); 
      });
  }
  $per_page = request()->has('per_page')?(int) request()->per_page : null;
  $pagination = $query->paginate($per_page);
  $pagination->appends([
      'sort'=>request()->sort,
      'filter'=>request()->filter,
      'per_page'=>request()->per_page
  ]);

    return response()->json(
        $pagination
    )
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET');
}
```

What should I do to get the result. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are same column name in your tables(`gender` in `user_details` and `users`), you need to specify the table name with the column, so that mysql can find the true column for you,

like this:

```php
    $query= $query->where('user_details.gender','LIKE','female');
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't know which table you are talking about when you are using Joins - unless you specify table names for each column mentioned in your query.

Replace these lines:

```
$query= $query->where('gender','LIKE','female');
$query= $query->where('matrimonial','LIKE','1');
```

with these lines:

```
$query= $query->where('users_details.gender','LIKE','female');
$query= $query->where('users_details.matrimonial','LIKE','1');
```